# In C++ and Qt how can I write these `#include <Q...>` to another few lines?

Tags: c++, qt, include

I wrote some code to create GUI with C++ and Qt. Firstly, I wrote the following

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
```

While writing these lines, I remembered when I used Python and Qt, to use Qt class, I had wrote like this.

```
from PyQt.Gui import *
from PyQt.GtCore import *
```

The question is: In C++ how can I write these `#include <Q...>` to another few lines like above?

Here is .cpp file I'm using.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  /* create label */
  QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello");
  label->show();

  /* create button */
  QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("World");
  button->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Here is .pro file.

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Sun Mar 19 23:12:24 2017
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = cppRunOnXcode
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG += debug
QT += widgets


# Input
SOURCES += cppRunOnXcode.cpp
```

Comment: In general in C++, you only want to include what you have to. Bringing in all of, say, the QtGUI headers when you only want a QPushButton and QLabel is incredibly wasteful and will slow down your whole build process.

Comment: @stefaanv: Yeah this question is related to it. But in that question, OP already know the way. In my case, before understanding the question I need understand C++ basic as Android400 answered. So now I can understand the question and the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include super header, like:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCore>
```

Basically, super headers are one-to-one related to Qt Modules.

Comment: when you add the module to your project in your pro file ( i.e. `QT += widgets` ), the directory `QtWidgets` is added automatically to your include directories. So, you just need to write `#include <QtWidgets>`.

Comment: Oh... It works as I wanted. It seems the direct answer of my question.

Comment: @Mike: it also worked. Thanks to your advise, I dived into the Xcode project and found the makefile which certainly define the path you mentioned. I didn't expect I get so much information from this simple question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ preprocessor has no wildcards. If you find yourself repeating the same includes and cluttering your code, you could write an umbrella header:

some_headers.h:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include "d.h"
```

and then in my_program.h:

```
#include "some_headers
```

Comment: OK I don't know that. So now I understand there is no way to do like Python's `import *` in C++. In Python, it's grammatically possible but in C++ programming there's no way such that. I learned a lot. Thank you.